# Change django form data before the actual validations take place

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am working on an app where i am using time fields to save time and i am using a jquery plugin to select the time. My problem is when i am selecting the time the plugin adds AM and PM with the time and django form validations returns invalid form.

I tried self.clean_field method and clean method to remove the am and pm from the time value submitted by the user. but not getting any way.

my models.py is

```
class Schedule(models.Model):

    day=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=DAY_OF_WEEK)
    start_time=models.TimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    end_time=models.TimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.day
```

my form is

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        widgets={
        'day':forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':True,'class':'day_class_name'}),
        'start_time':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'schedule_start_time'}),
        'end_time':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'schedule_end_time'}),

    }
time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']


def clean(self):
    print ' i am in clean method'
    #start=self.cleaned_data['start_time']
    #end=self.cleaned_data['end_time']
    #print start, end
   # print self.cleaned_data
    return self.cleaned_data

def clean_start_time(self):
    #print dir(self)
    start=self.get('start_time',None)
    print start
    #print self.data
    #print ' i am in clean_start_time method'
    #start=self.cleaned_data['start_time']
    #print start
    #if  start and ('AM' or 'PM' in start):
        # start.replace('AM','')
        # start.replace('PM','')
        # return start
    return start


def clean_end_time(self):
   # print ' i am in clean end_time method'
    start=self.cleaned_data['end_time']
    #print start
    #if  start and ('AM' or 'PM' in start):
     #   start.replace('AM','')
     #   start.replace('PM','')
        #return start
    return start
```

can someone guide me which method i will have to override to remove the am and pm from the value before the actual django form validations take place.
Help will be appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to configure your jquery plugin so that it feeds your form fields with valid values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is based on a complete misunderstanding of what is happening. You do *not* get any value with "am" or "pm" in the cleaned_data. Django converts the string form to an actual instance of `datetime.time`, and that is all you need.

Your problem is actually caused by your failure to set the time format correctly. Instead of randomly putting a list called `time_formats` at the end of the form, where it will be completely ignored, you need to set a value called `input_formats` on the time field itself:

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_time = forms.TimeField(input_formats=['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p'])
    ...
```

Now the field will accept times with am/pm, and you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: No, still doesn't work.formse.errors

[{'start_time': [u'Enter a valid time.'], 'end_time': [u'Enter a valid time.']}, {'start_time': [u'Enter a valid time.'], 'end_time': [u'Enter a valid time.']}, {'start_time': [u'Enter a valid time.'], 'end_time': [u'Enter a valid time.']}, {'start_time': [u'Enter a valid time.'], 'end_time': [u'Enter a valid time.']}, {'start_time': [u'Enter a valid time.'], 'end_time': [u'Enter a valid time.']}, {'start_time': [u'Enter a valid time.'], 'end_time': [u'Enter a valid time.']}, {'start_time': [u'Enter a valid time.'], 'end_time': [u'Enter a valid time.']}]

Comment: request,POST is 
<QueryDict: {u'form-0-day': [u'MO'], u'form-3-start_time': [u'10:00:00'], u'form-3-end_time': [u'18:00:00'], u'form-4-start_time': [u'10:00:00'], u'form-2-start_time': [u'10:00:00'], u'form-5-start_time': [u'10:00:00'], u'form-3-day': [u'TH'], u'form-6-start_time': [u'10:00:00'], u'form-1-start_time': [u'10:00:00'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'pFE4CWOINE1n4Do5gelv2WZMLu5U2qzE'], u'form-1-day': [u'TU'], u'form-4-end_time': [u'18:00:00'], u'form-6-end_time': [u'18:00:00'], u'form-6-day': [u'SU'], u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'7'], u'form-4-day': [u'FR'], .......... }>

Comment: OK, so you can see from that that the times don't have am/pm after all, but they do have seconds. So your formats should include `"%H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: yes, Thanks a lot Daniel. It was mistake of seconds. works after adding seconds in format.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work. Override the clean method.

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ScheduleForm, self).clean()
        # Here you remove what you need
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: When i call clean_data in clean method it returns the data after performing the validations

Comment: cleaned_data is 

{'close': False, 'day': u'MO'}
{'close': False, 'start_time': None, 'day': u'TU', 'end_time': None}
{'close': False, 'start_time': None, 'day': u'WE', 'end_time': None}
{'close': False, 'start_time': None, 'day': u'TH', 'end_time': None}
{'close': False, 'start_time': None, 'day': u'FR', 'end_time': None}
{'close': False, 'start_time': None, 'day': u'SA', 'end_time': None}
{'close': False, 'start_time': None, 'day': u'SU', 'end_time': None}